# SharePoint 2019 On-Premises with SPFx from Local Machine

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, spfx, sharepoint-on-prem

I am new to SP and SPFx. I want to develop some solutions using SPFx, but I want to be working outside the server from my local machine.

I mean I would like to use VS code from my machine and connect to our On-Premises SP Farm Server and do the development rather than connecting to the server through RDP and do the development there.

Also, any suggestions for beginner SP developer such as working with HTML/CSS or TypeScript/CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you can access the SharePoint server from your development machine (i.e. from a browser), there is no problem with what you are planning to do.
For the required setup, follow the advice of Andrew Connell from his blog:
https://www.voitanos.io/blog/definitive-guide-sharepoint-framework-sharepoint-server-2019/

Essentially it's:

Install Node.js LTS v8 (specifically, Node.js v8.17.0 )
Then, at the command prompt:

```
npm install gulp-cli@2.3.0 yo@3.1.1 @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.10.0 --global
```

This way, you’re using the most recent versions of Node.js, Gulp-CLI, Yeoman and the generator SPFx to create new SPFx v1.4.1 projects for SharePoint Server 2019.

If you need to work with multiple versions of node.js, the first thing that you should do is install a version manager for node.js. For Windows that would be nvm-windows (https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows). For other systems there are other node version managers.

As to suggestions for a beginner SP developer, I would advise you to learn HTML, CSS, JavaScript and TypeScript. There are lots of tutorials out there. Then, for the SPFx part, use the very detailed documentation Microsoft provides at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part.

Comment: Clear enough thanks. I am an expert developer so already familiar with mentioned web technologies but not with SP. So, as you said I will deploy the site that I will work with and will connect to it using that guide. I am considering working with TypeScript as already have been working with React JavaScript for descent time but anyway will appreciate your advice about that; particularly not facing bugs and issues for compatibility with SP2019 On-Prem.